# Unable to use configparser in ai-platform custom prediction

Tags: setuptools, google-cloud-ml

I'm looking at a way to use `configparser` in my predictor code for custom prediction routine.
I tried following code snippet

**common.cfg**

```
[MODEL]
VERSION=config-true
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'joblib==0.13.0'
]

setup(
    name='test',
    description='Custom prediction routine',
    version=0.1,
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    scripts=['src/predictor.py', 'config/common.cfg']
)
```

**predictor.py**

```
import os
import joblib
import subprocess
import configparser

class CustomPredictor(object):
    def __init__(self, model, config):
        self._model = model
        self._config = config

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):
        version_value = self._config.get('MODEL', 'VERSION', fallback='config-false')
        print(f'version value = {version_value}', flush=True) # printing config-false

        preprocessed_input = self._preprocess(instances)

        score = self._model.predict(preprocessed_input)

        print(f'predicted score {score}', flush=True)
        return score.to_list()

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, model_dir):
        config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        result = config.read('config/common.cfg')
        print(f'read config result: {result}', flush=True) # empty
        print(f'config sections: {config.sections()}', flush=True) # empty

        subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"]) # don't see the config file or folder

        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib")
        model = joblib.load(model_path)

        return cls(model, config)
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake I was doing, during deployment of custom prediction routine, ai-platform keeps files under `/tmp/custom_lib/bin/` and keeps execution path as the root directory. So, in my code, I have updated the config path to something like this

```
config_file = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() / 'common.cfg'
config.read(config_file)
```

This fixes the issue!

Note: I also believe we need to keep config files under **scripts** tag because when deployment logic installs the package, setuptools will copy the script to ai-platform defined PATH and make it available.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code, it printed expected result:

```
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
result = config.read('common.cfg')
print(f'read config result: {result}', flush=True) # empty
print(f'config sections: {config.sections()}', flush=True) # empty
```

#### output is

```
read config result: ['common.cfg']
config sections: ['MODEL']
```

#### So probable error could be path of your common.cfg file.

when I copy your code and ran it it showed empty list as output, because file was in same directory not inside config directory, But as soon as i corrected path it printed expected result.

Comment: my code works locally, the challenge I'm facing is packaging the config file along with predictor code and making it work after deploying to ai-platform

Comment: Is directory structure same there as well?

Comment: nope, I don't have access to configure directory structure there, all I provide is the tar.gz file and it unwraps as per their code (which is a black box)
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#deploy_your_custom_prediction_routine

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Configure `setup.py` and add `configparser` there.

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'joblib==0.13.0',
    'configparser'
]
```

2. Pass config parser as a package using the `package-uris`, when you create the Model. From [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/#files) I found the tar.gz file already.
   Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/notebooks/samples/pytorch/text_classification/text_classification_using_pytorch_and_ai_platform.ipynb) example, when we pass a PyTorch package, in your case download the file from pypi and put it into a GCS Bucket, from there just define it when you create your model:

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create {MODEL_VERSION} --model {MODEL_NAME} \
 --origin=gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{MODEL_DIR}/ \
 --python-version=3.7 \
 --runtime-version={RUNTIME_VERSION} \
 --package-uris=gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{PACKAGES_DIR}/text_classification-0.1.tar.gz,
gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/configparser-5.0.0.tar.gz  \
 --machine-type=mls1-c4-m4 \
 --prediction-class=model.CustomModelPrediction
```

Comment: Thanks @gogasca
Let me try that. Btw I believed `configparser` came out of the box with python 
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Lib